# How to use google sheets to transpose a set of cells that correspond to a specific input date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to set up a calendar-type to-do list on google sheets. I would like to be able to take a date from a certain cell on sheet 1, and use it to match up to a to-do list from another sheet (sheet 2) that corresponds with the same date that's at the top of the column, then transpose the data from sheet 2 onto sheet 1. Should I try to use a transpose function? Hlookup?

Answer (score 0):

`query` function would work well:

`=query(Sheet1!A:D,"select * where A = date '"&text(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by B,C,D ",1)`

[image]

For ease, I've shown it on the same sheet.

More about `query`:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

**Some alternatives:**

`=query(transpose(Sheet1!1:4),"select * where Col1 = date '"&text(A7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by Col2 ",1)`

[image]

`=transpose(query(transpose(Sheet1!1:4),"select * where Col1 = date '"&text(A7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by Col2 ",1))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I change it so instead of reading a column (A) it reads a row